# SQL : query of future appointments order by nearest date

Tags: sql

Table `Appointments`:

```
id  int(11) Auto Increment  
appointment_number  varchar(150) NULL   
facility_id int(11) 
practitioner_id int(11) 
calendar_id int(11) 
calendar_service_id int(11)     
patient_id  int(11) 
patient_relative_id int(11) NULL    
first_name  varchar(200)    
last_name   varchar(200) NULL   
email   varchar(100) NULL   
phone   varchar(100) NULL   
birthdate   date NULL   
fg_gender   tinyint(2) NULL 
start_time  datetime    
end_time    datetime
```

Comment: which sql engine are you using? also provide test data and expected result in tabular form.

Comment: That's terrible table design. An appointment does not have a firstname, lastname, email, phone, birthdate or gender. Those should be attributes of the patient table and do not belong in the appointments table.

Comment: SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE end_time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ORDER BY start_time

Comment: Yes. the table's design is wrong as @SchmitzIT said.

To order by latest date use : `order by start_time DESC`

Comment: i think its mySQL, my mentor ask me this question. I am still very new to SQL.

Comment: If you don't know what DB you use, include a screenshot of the rogram you are writing your SQL into; it might help us determine what you use

Comment: it is a question in a chat, Thank You Very Much for the help !

Comment: @wishnumurti312 - If this table was designed by your mentor, he should not be teaching SQL. Ask him if he knows what 3rd normal form is.

Answer (score 0):

I think from the `tinyint(2)` reference that this is either SQLite or MySQL/MariaDB. As such, for SQLite:

```
 SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE start_time > datetime('now') ORDER BY start_time ASC
```

For MySQL/Maria:

```
 SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE start_time > now() ORDER BY start_time ASC
```